# Angular 6 - logout user when only browser close not on refresh

Tags: javascript, angular

logout the user when he close the browser not on refresh

`@HostListener('window:beforeunload', [ '$event' ])
unloadHandler(event) {
this.logout()
}`

`logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem('id');
    this.router.navigate(["/login"]);
  }`

I use this, it works but the user also logout on refresh the browser

Comment: where you stored your user login details.

Comment: localstroage @SachinfromPune

Comment: Please always provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

In your app.component.ts

Add before your constructor(),

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload')
  unloadHandler(event) {
    localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
  }
```

Comment: If I use this it is also working on page refresh, I need this function to work only when the user close the browser or tab

Comment: please go through this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/detect-browser-or-tab-closing